# Generation of array temporaries for pure functions in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

My question is about some puzzling behavior of `gfortran` (gcc version 8.1.0 (GCC)) in treating temporary arrays. The code below is compiled with `-O3 -Warray-temporaries`.

Consider the following possibility to construct sum of direct products of matrices:

```
program Pexam1
  use Maux, only: kron
  double precision:: A(3, 3), B(3, 3)
  double precision:: C(5, 5), D(5, 5)
  double precision:: rAC(15, 15), rBD(15, 15), r1(15, 15), r2(15, 15)
  
  r1 = -kron(3, A, 5, C) - kron(3, B, 5, D)
!                             1
! Warning: Creating array temporary at (1)

  rAC = -kron(3, A, 5, C)
!           1
! Warning: Creating array temporary at (1)   

  r2 = rAC - kron(3, B, 5, D)
end program Pexam1
```

There are two warnings, but I do not expect the second one (in `rAC = -kron(3, A, 5, C)`). *Why?* Simply in the first line `r1 = -kron(3, A, 5, C) - kron(3, B, 5, D)` the identical first part is evaluated *just fine without a temporary array*. What is the reason for this inconsistency? What should one keep in mind to avoid unnecessary creation of temporary arrays?

The module `Maux` is as follows

```
module Maux
 contains
 pure function kron(nA, A, nB, B) result (C)
    ! // direct product of matrices 
    integer, intent(in)         :: nA, nB
    double precision, intent(in)  :: A(nA, nA), B(nB, nB)
    double precision              :: C(nA*nB, nA*nB)
    integer :: iA, jA, iB, jB

    forall (iA=1:nA, jA=1:nA, iB=1:nB, jB=1:nB)&
         C(iA + (iB-1) * nA, jA + (jB-1) * nA) = A(iA, jA) * B(iB, jB)

  end function kron
end module Maux
```

Comment: Do you see similar warnings when you have a non-buggy main program?

Comment: Experiment - change the `forall` construct inside `kron` to an equivalent `do concurrent` construct.

Comment: @francescalus Yes I do. Copy-pasting and shortening  names of variables introduced some misprints.  Now I corrected everything. The message remains.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The change `forall` to `do concurrent` does not change anything.

Comment: I see my comment expressing gratitude to @yarchik for conducting the experiment I suggested has been deleted.  I wonder if this more extended, and somewhat circumlocutory version, will survive the auto-winnowing which I suspect removed the earlier version.

Answer (score 4):

If you build this program, you'll notice an array temporary is only created in case you're evaluating `kron` with the minus sign:

```
 
 program Pexam1
  use Maux, only: kron
  double precision:: A(3, 3), B(3, 3)
  double precision:: C(5, 5), D(5, 5)
  double precision:: rAC(15, 15), rBD(15, 15), r1(15, 15), r2(15, 15)
  

  rAC = kron(3, A, 5, C) ! no temporary

  r2  = -kron(3, B, 5, D) ! temporary
end program Pexam1
```

Don't forget that every `assignment` in fortran (`=`) is a separate operation than what happens to the r.h.s. of the equal sign.
So when `kron` is negative, the compiler needs to:

1. evaluate `kron(3,B,5,D)`, put it in a temporary (let's call it `tmp`)
2. evaluate `-tmp`
3. assign the result of this temporary operation (could have any type/kind) to `r2`

Apparently, gFortran is good enough that when you have step 1. only (positive assignment), the result of the operation is copied directly to `rAC` without any temporaries (I guess because `rAC` has the same rank, type, shape as the result of the call to `kron`).

Comment: Yes, gfortran is good enough in `r1`, but there is a negative assignment, which it can deal with. That was unexpected for me, therefore I thought it should also be smart in  evaluating `rAC` . It is excellent that gfortran is good in recognizing some design patterns, but it is not consistently good.

Comment: gfortran is an open-source project and its improvements depend on the commitment from its userbase!

Comment: I fully agree, it is amazing what the community is doing!

Comment: There is unfortunately no "grand unified theory" for optimizing array expressions (in this case, avoiding temporaries) whereby a small set of optimizing passes would "automatically" handle the vast majority of cases. Therefore Fortran compilers must implement a sort of pattern matching for each kind of optimization, and there's a near unlimited number of possible optimizations. Seems Gfortran doesn't implement avoiding a temporary array for simple negation.